# Laravel error add photo_id to my migration

Tags: laravel, migration

i'm trying to add a photo to my scooter advertisement.
but when i'm trying to migrate i get this error the whole time:

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'photo_id' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `scooter` add constraint `scooter_photo_id_foreign` foreign key (`photo_id`) references `photo` (`id`))
```

i do not get what i'm doing wrong.

**scooter migration**
    class CreateScooterTable extends Migration
{

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('scooter', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->foreign('photo_id')->references('id')->on('photo');
        $table->string("price");
        $table->bigInteger("description");
        $table->string("km");
        $table->string("lincenseplatecolor");
        $table->string("color");
        $table->string("name");
        $table->boolean("sold");
        $table->string("motortype");
        $table->string("brand");
        $table->string("topspeed");
        $table->string("contstructionYear");
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('scooter');
}
```

}
**photo migration:**

```
class CreatePhotoTable extends Migration
```

{

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('photo', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('src');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('photo');
}
```

}

i do not get what i'm doing wrong and love if you guys would know the awnser (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I had to change the time stamps in the filename.
that way photo id existed when people wanted create a new relation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `photo_id` to your migration.

This will add a foreign key constraint but won't create the `photo_id` column

```
$table->foreign('photo_id')->references('id')->on('photo');
```

You will need to specify the column and then add the constraint like so:

```
$table->bigInteger("photo_id")->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('photo_id')->references('id')->on('photo');
```

Comment: i get this eror    Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `jmaaskan0255_maaskantscooters`.`scooter` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL
: alter table `scooter` add constraint `scooter_photo_id_foreign` foreign key (`photo_id`) references `photo` (`id`))

when i'm pasting the code in the create scooter tabble